# How to make a command prompt shortcut run a script on starting?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, cmd

I can make a customized command prompt shortcut on my desktop to start in a particular directory and have some specified dimensions etc.

Now i have a script that sets some environment variables for the prompt and want to run it as soon as this shortcut is clicked.

How do i tell cmd or powershell to run this script in the current shell window and then show the shell ?

Comment: What do you mean the current shell window? It would help to show the files you are using and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes i mean the current shell window. I am deploying a rather complex system and this is a simple use case functionality that i need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `cmd` change the shortcut target to

```
%COMSPEC% /k C:\PATH\TO\your.cmd
```

and set the environment variables in `your.cmd`:

```
@echo off

set FOO=23
set BAR=42
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the properties of the shortcut to include the `file`(scriptpath) and the `noexit`(to not close when done) parameter in the target-path. Example for target-path:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -file "c:\users\graimer\desktop\testscript.ps1"
```